# UIScrollView paging load from nib just 1 NIB show

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, paging

i'm new on object-C, i want show some NIB file to UIScrollView with paging, i'm do it but just 1 NIB showing, other nib not show, the sample i make 2 page on each page have NIB, this is code :

```
bbottompageused = NO;
    CGRect frame;
int tview=2;

mycontact = [[MyContact alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyContact" bundle:nil];
myphoto = [[MyPhoto alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPhoto" bundle:nil];


frame.origin.x = self.midleScroll.frame.size.width * 1;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.midleScroll.frame.size;
[self.midleScroll addSubview:mycontact.view];

frame.origin.x = self.midleScroll.frame.size.width * 2;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.midleScroll.frame.size;
[self.midleScroll addSubview:myphoto.view];



    self.midleScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.midleScroll.frame.size.width * tview, self.midleScroll.frame.size.height);
    self.midlePage.currentPage = 0;
    self.midlePage.numberOfPages = tview;
```

Have anyone suggestion for solve this ?
Thanks all,

Answer (score 0):

You configure the frame but you don't assign this frame to `myContact.view` and `myPhoto.view`.

Hence, both of the `myContact.view.frame` and `myPhoto.view.frame` remain unchanged.

Do the following:

```
bbottompageused = NO;
CGRect frame;
int tview=2;

mycontact = [[MyContact alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyContact" bundle:nil];
myphoto = [[MyPhoto alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPhoto" bundle:nil];

frame.origin.x = self.midleScroll.frame.size.width * 1;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.midleScroll.frame.size;
// Assign the frame
myContact.view.frame = frame;
[self.midleScroll addSubview:mycontact.view];

frame.origin.x = self.midleScroll.frame.size.width * 2;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.midleScroll.frame.size;
// Assign the frame
myPhoto.view.frame = frame;
[self.midleScroll addSubview:myphoto.view];


self.midleScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.midleScroll.frame.size.width * tview, self.midleScroll.frame.size.height);
self.midlePage.currentPage = 0;
self.midlePage.numberOfPages = tview;
```

Comment: if i am correct, both of your nib were getting added to the scroll view, but one upon other, making only myPhoto's view to be visible. This was because, both of their frame were unchanged and hence the same.

Answer (score 0):

assign the frame that you have to your views (myContact, myPhoto) and then add them to the scroll view.